# In a Quarto book how to you specify that all chapters should not be numbered?

Tags: html, quarto

I know I can specify individual sections are not numbered by adding `{.unnumbered}` to a heading. How can I set that as a global option so none of the chapters in my book are numbered?

If I set the `number-sections: false` in the yaml header like this:

```yaml
format:
  html:
    theme: cosmo
    css: styles.css
    number-sections: false
```

it does not suppress the numbering from the navigation bar.

That is, with the `number-sections: false` set and this in my qmd:

```
# CSS Combinators

## CSS Combinators

-   Defines relationship between selectors.
-   There are four
```

it renders like this:
[image]

With `{.unnumbered}` in the qmd:

```
# CSS Combinators {.unnumbered}

## CSS Combinators

-   Defines relationship between selectors.
-   There are four
```

It renders like this:

[image]

Comment: Have just gone through the quarto docs for [`book options`](https://quarto.org/docs/reference/projects/books.html#meta-project-type-upper), but didn't find any option to do this globally.

Comment: Do you want to remove all section numbering in your book or just the chapter heading numbers?

Comment: I was hoping to remove all the numbering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to remove all the section numbering in your book, you can simply set the output format option `number-sections` to `false`

```
project:
  type: book

book:
  title: "Section Unnumbering"
  author: "Shafee"
  date: "7/31/2022"
  chapters:
    - index.qmd
    - intro.qmd
    - summary.qmd
    - references.qmd

bibliography: references.bib

format:
  html:
    theme: cosmo
    css: styles.css
    number-sections: false
```

**Update**

So it seems that specifying `number-sections` to `false` works when the screen is wider but fails to work when screen gets narrowed, numbering still remains in chapter headings in the narrowed case.

To forcibly hiding the chapter number, we need to modify the corresponding CSS class which is `.chapter-number`.

**styles.css**

```
.chapter-number {
  display: none; 
}
```

[image: narrowed_page]

Comment: That is a good idea.  Unfortunately, I tied it earlier and it didn't work right.  I updated the question to show the issue.  I am thinking this is a bug.

Comment: @itsMeInMiami, but I don't get any numbering. Updated my answer with a screenshot. Can you provide a screenshot of your whole page of the book?

Comment: Try making the page narrow.  When it shifts the table of contents to the top of the page it draws the number.  When it is wide it disappears.... I am going to open an issue on GitHub.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @itsMeInMiami, solved the issue using CSS. Check my updated answer.

Comment: Nicely done.  I opened an issue on GitHub.  So hopefully the team can fix the root problem when they get back from RStudio::Conf.